# MySQL Multiple Commands in a Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, procedure

For a class assignment I need to move a record from the Checked_Out_Media table to a History table, where the tables are identical. Then I need to delete the record from the Checked_Out_Media Table. I've gotten it down to this:

```
Create Procedure spMoveToHistory( IN in_UserID char(6), IN in_MediaBarcode char(3) )

BEGIN

    SELECT @NextRow := (MAX(History_TUID) + 1)
    From History;

    Insert into History
        Select @NextRow, COM.User_ID, COM.Media_Barcode,
            COM.Checked_Out_Date, COM.Return_Date
        From Checked_Out_Media COM
        Where COM.User_ID = in_UserID AND
            COM.Media_Barcode = in_MediaBarcode;
END;
```

The above code seems to work perfectly fine until I run it. It doesn't do anything, good or bad. When I check the procedure after it is created, It shows that there is an error at the End statement. I'm not sure why that only shows up AFTER I create it... Either way, I was hoping someone could clarify why the above doesn't work so I can try to add the below code. **Also, the main reason for this post is to ask: Is it even possible to implement more than one transaction in a procedure?**

```
Delete From checked_out_media
    Where User_ID = in_UserID  AND Media_Barcode = in_MediaBarcode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your stored procedure is with how the commands are separated from each other. As mysql documentation on [defining stored programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) says:

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program
>   containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql
>   itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must
>   redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire
>   stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command. The
>   following example shows how to do this for the dorepeat() procedure
>   just shown. The delimiter is changed to // to enable the entire
>   definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then
>   restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ;
>   delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the
>   server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.
>
> ```
> mysql> delimiter //
>
> mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
>     -> BEGIN
>     ->   SET @x = 0;
>     ->   REPEAT SET @x = @x + 1; UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
>     -> END
>     -> // Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> delimiter ;
> ```

Concerning your 2nd question: you are not executing any transactions in your stored proc, your question is about if you can execute multiple sql commands within a stored procedure. The answer is yes, you can execute multiple sql commands, see above sample code.

Actually, you may want to consider encluding the insert and the delete into a single transaction, but this is a different question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Shadow But I should have mentioned that i'm using phpMyAdmin where it allows/forces me to tell it what delimiter I am using when creating a procedure - in which I use "//" and even with doing so, my code still won't work. Any ideas on which part is wrong?

Comment: It is in the answer: the final end is terminated by what you provided in the delimiter (//).

Comment: I suppose... but I guess knowing that doesn't help me since I can't seem to implement it in the above code. I just don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: There is nothing to implement. Instead of `end;` simply write `end//`

Comment: This code never ended up working. I rewrote it differently by grabbing each column data into variables, then inserting into History values of variables. Thank you for making it clear that it was possible to do so.